# Running n MATLAB instances using python in parallel

Tags: python, matlab

I would like to run some tests on MATLAB  which usually takes 2 days and I have 3 such tests( so 3 x 2 = 6 days ). 
So, I run three MATLAB sessions on my windows machine and run my three tests (in parallel) which reduces my test time from 6 days to 2 days.

I would like to do similar stuff on python to invoke three MATLAB instances.(I can do that serially , but not parallely)

```
import matlab.engine as MAT_E
eng=MAT_E.start_matlab()

test_id=1
isTestDone = eng.runTest1(test_id,nargout=1)   # runTest1 is a .m file which needs to be run

test_id=2
isTestDone = eng.runTest2(test_id,nargout=1)   # runTest2 is a .m file which needs to be run

test_id=3
isTestDone = eng.runTest3(test_id,nargout=1)   # runTest3 is a .m file which needs to be run
```

Does anyone know how I can do similar stuff in parallel?

Please let me know if you have any questions/suggestions/comments ?

EDITED/Added the runTest1 skeleton

```
function out1 = runTest1(test_id)

% some processing happens and variable 'x' is generated 

if x < 0.1
    % some warning
    warning('the samples are incosistent')
    keyboard;
end

if x > 99
    error('simulation encountered some out of bound values')
end


# some more processing 

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MATLAB documentation for the `start_matlab` function [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/matlab.engine.start_matlab.html#buj7y8n-eng) says:

> Each time you call matlab.engine.start_matlab, it starts a new MATLAB process.

So, start a new MATLAB process for each test, and run them all. We also find from the documentation [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-matlab-functions-asynchronously-from-python.html) that we need to use the `background=True` argument when running functions so that Python can call all 3 tests without waiting for them to finish.

```py
import matlab.engine as MAT_E
eng1 = MAT_E.start_matlab()
eng2 = MAT_E.start_matlab()
eng3 = MAT_E.start_matlab()

# start running the tests
test1_future = eng1.runTest1(1,nargout=1,background=True)
test2_future = eng2.runTest2(2,nargout=1,background=True)
test3_future = eng3.runTest3(3,nargout=1,background=True)

# get the results of all the tests (waits for tests to finish)
result1 = test1_future.result()
result2 = test2_future.result()
result3 = test3_future.result()

# do something with the results...
```

If you had a lot more than 3 it would probably be worth doing this with a loop.

Comment: Thanks Dominic D .. I will try that out now.

Comment: Hi Dominic .. It worked... Thanks for the input.. Quick question . The function 'runTest1.m' incurs error/keyboard situation (test function has error and keyboard in it and they does invoke on some inputs)   and I need to know if such case happened in python.... I tried to use stdout=out  and stderr=err   in the test1_future line and tried to get err.getvalue() , but it never prints even though error occurs

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/redirect-standard-output-and-error-to-python.html     .. this is what i followed      out=io.StringIO()   err=io.StringIO() test1_future = eng1.runTest1(1,nargout=1,stdout=out,stderr=err,background=True)

Comment: I think i have a solution for capturing Error ... I'm using test1_future .cancelled() and that will be TRUE when any error occurs...  Now, I'm trying to capture keyboard

Comment: By keyboard do you mean that you're trying to capture console output? (what you would see in the matlab console when running the function) Or trying to capture something like a keyboard interrupt?

Comment: I have added/edited runTest1 function in my question.  Whenever error /keyboard interrupt happens in any of the background MATLAB processes, I would like python to know so that python can notify the person about error/keyboard_interrupt that simulation is errored out (or) simulation is stuck at keyboard interrupt..

Comment: What I did for notifying error to python was `test1_future = eng1.runTest1(1,nargout=1,stdout=out,stderr=err,background=True) `             and when the runTest1 errors out , I can always check test1_future.cancelled() flag  . but I cannot think of any way for keyboard interrupts

Comment: `keyboard` pauses execution of the function until you resume it with the keyboard, but this never happens because there's no keyboard connected to the background function. So `test1_future.done()` will always return false? I don't believe there to be a way to send keyboard input from python to the MATLAB function, so an easier option would be to split the function into 2 parts. The first just generates and returns `x`. Then Python can interact with the keyboard and decide what to do next. Finally, the extra processing is done by a second MATLAB function.

Comment: Thats true Dominic.. Thanks for all the help